# Stop Drive from automatically loading

Tags: google-drive, autostart

When I go into the preferences in the Drive icon in the system tray and uncheck the "Start Google Drive automatically when you start your computer" the icon still loads.
I went into auto-runs and unchecked it but it still loads.
I don't want it loading at start, I'll start it when I need it.
Help appreciated.

RangerGord

Comment: Did you tried to disable it from Start Up in the Task Manager ?

Answer (score 2):

Try removing it from auto run list using [AutoRuns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) it is a powerful tool from Microsoft for such tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Besider autoruns check, run **Task Scheduler** and inspect scheduled tasks you find there. Google uses this location for various tasks (such as GoogleUpdater for Chrome update check) which are launched after user login or in some regular intervals.

Disable (or delete) unwanted tasks here.

Answer (score 0):

This might not work for you but this was my situation:

I have multiple profiles on my mac: one for home and one for work.  I wanted my work profile to login automatically, and my home profile never to login.

The only way I could find to accomplish this was to block it with permissions under "get info" window.

Seems like there should be a way to block just the autostart with OSX and not relying on Google's settings.

*wringing fists at Google*